# Lista encadeada em C- adicionar!

Tags: c

Estou com duvida em um exercício e se alguém pudesse me ajudar seria muito bom! Obrigado desde já!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Numeros {
    int numero;
    struct Numeros *next;
};

void adicionar (int n, struct Numeros **here) {
    struct Numeros *temporario;

    if((*here)->next == NULL)
       {getch();
       (*here)->numero=n;
       }
       else if(((*here)->next->numero!=n)&&((*here)->next->numero>n))
       {
           temporario=(struct Numeros*)malloc(sizeof(struct Numeros));
           temporario=(*here)->next;
           temporario->numero=n;
           temporario->next=(*here)->next;
           (*here)->next=temporario;
           free(temporario);
           }
}

void remover (int n, struct Numeros **here) {
// 1- Verificar se não existem elementos na lista
// 1.1- sair

// 2- Caso exista elementos, verificar se o atual éo que se deseja remover
// 2.1- atualizar os ponteiros

// 3- Caso não seja o elemento procurado, avançar na lista procurando!
}

void imprimir (struct Numeros *here) {
    printf("[%d]", here->numero);
    if (here->next != NULL) 
        {
        imprimir(here->next); // manda imprimir o proximo!
        }
}

 int main (){
struct Numeros *head = NULL;

int flag = 0, numero;
do {
    printf("1) adicionar\n");
    printf("2) remover\n");
    printf("3) imprimir\n");
    printf("0) sair\n");
    printf("Informe uma opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &flag);

    switch(flag){
        case 0: // sair
            break;
        case 1: // adicionar
            printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Informe o valor para ser adicionado: ");
            scanf("%d", &numero);
            adicionar(numero, &head);
            printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
            break;
        case 2: // remover
            printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Informe o valor para ser removido: ");
            scanf("%d", &numero);
            remover(numero, &head);
            printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
            break;
        case 3: // imprimir
            printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
            (head != NULL) ? imprimir(head) : printf("Não existem elementos na lista\n");;
            printf("\n");
            printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Opcao invalida\n");
    }

} while (flag);

free(head);

return 0;
}
```

Em relação ao

```
void remover(int n,struct Numeros **here)
```

não precisam se preocupar pois ainda não comecei a desenvolver e nem a fazer, por isso gostaria de ter a oportunidade de tentar, mas a minha duvida esta no adicionar, já a partir do

```
if((*here)->next == NULL)
```

começa a ter falhas no programa. Se alguém puder me explicar o que está errado e o que falta me ajudaria bastante na compreensão. Valeu!!!

Comment: No inicio tens `head = NULL` quando acedes a `(* here)->next` ou seja NULL->next, deve dar seg.fault. Talvez juntat um `if((*here) == NULL)...`

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar:

```
(*(*here)).next == NULL
```

Em vez de usar:

```
(*here)->next == NULL
```